# How do I restore Windows 10 Quick Search functionality after Feature Update 1803 install?

Tags: windows-10, windows-search, cortana, windows-10-v1803

After installing the Windows 10 Feature Update version 1803 on May 8, 2018 the Windows Quick Search function stopped working. When I am on the desktop or press the Windows key and begin typing, no search box opens and no search occurs.

I consistently see the following two entries in the Windows Event Viewer Application Log whenever I try to use Quick Search:

**Error** application log entry:

```
Faulting application name: SearchUI.exe, version: 10.0.17134.48, time stamp: 0x5ae3f1dd
Faulting module name: edgehtml.dll, version: 11.0.17134.48, time stamp: 0xf3c5bd61
Exception code: 0xc0000602
Fault offset: 0x00000000004e6bba
Faulting process id: 0x3e74
Faulting application start time: 0x01d3ef9220aac5d5
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy\SearchUI.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\edgehtml.dll
Report Id: 3915f2eb-1417-4b6d-b269-411cfc2eb5f6
Faulting package full name: Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_1.10.7.17134_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
Faulting package-relative application ID: CortanaUI
```

Related **Information** application log entry that follows the Error entry:

```
Fault bucket 1244940528049283667, type 5
Event Name: MoAppCrash
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_1.10.7.17134_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
P2: praid:CortanaUI
P3: 10.0.17134.48
P4: 5ae3f1dd
P5: edgehtml.dll
P6: 11.0.17134.48
P7: f3c5bd61
P8: c0000602
P9: 00000000004e6bba
P10: 

Attached files:
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERD321.tmp.mdmp
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERD601.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERD621.tmp.xml
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERD62B.tmp.csv
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERD67A.tmp.txt

These files may be available here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_Microsoft.Window_7ebde89e2a8adfd3a73e49d3d17ff57f6a5ec7_7bec4e88_6352d9a9

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: 3915f2eb-1417-4b6d-b269-411cfc2eb5f6
Report Status: 268435456
Hashed bucket: ff9df3088f9345a43146ead074dd6253
Cab Guid: 0
```

Since the Windows 1803 Feature Update was just installed, I did not want to make a bad situation worse by restoring the references edgehtml.dll from my original install disc image.

Has anyone encountered this situation and successfully resolved it?

Thanks,
Rob

Comment: If you restore EdgeHTML from any version except 1803 you will make things work, and if you restore an older version of EdgeHTML 17, you will make things work.  Don’t do that, it won’t work, and will create a problem that can fixed.

Comment: SearchUI crashes. [Import this .reg file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8wd3xvt76l9f9j3/WER_SearchUI.reg?dl=1) to configure Windows Error Reporting to generate dumps in C:\localdumps. Now try to open search and if you see searchuiNUMBER.exe.dmp files in C:\localdumps, [download and import this .regfile](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wz2dspshz5pu85t/WER_SearchUI_uninstall.reg?dl=1) to stop dump creation. Now zup the dmps and share the zip via OneDrive and post the link here. I'll analyze the dump and I can submit them to my MS contacts.

Comment: @magicandre1981 -- Here is a link to the zipped SearchUI dumpfiles generated (five DMP files in the zip archive): https://www.dropbox.com/s/4c1oo8jujczkcjy/SearchUI-dumpfiles-2018052101.zip?dl=0

Comment: the dumps show that you use the Fall Creators Update 16299, not the April update 17134. have you done a rollback and still get the crash? there are JS operations which load HTML and during init of Font related code the fatal crash occurs (edgehtml!ApplyFontFace so @font-face is used in the CSS).

Comment: @magicandre1981: Thanks for the info! That's odd the dump shows Fall Creates Update 16299. I checked with both msinfo32.exe and winver.exe and they show Version 1803 (OS Build 17134.48). Regardless, does the dump include the font name? This could be as simple as a corrupt font file in the Fonts directory. I keep backups of font files, so it would be easy to restore any of them. I just don't want to restore the entire default set, if I can avoid it.

Comment: I see this fragment of the in the dump: **Segoe,Arial,sans-serif**. so open a cmd.exe as admin run **sfc /scannow** and **DISM /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth** look if this repairs the corrupted files.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information, @magicandre1981! The information you posted gave me what I needed to resolve the issue. 

It was not a case of corrupt font files. It was an issue with over-aggressive font management by met.  

I did an in-place update of Windows using the 1803 installation media. After Windows finished updating, Cortana search functionality was restored and functioning as expected. 

Again, thanks for digging through the dumpfiles. The information you found got me pointed in the right direction!

Best regards,
Rob

Comment: "over-aggressive font management " have you manually deleted fonts?